# What's the technical name for Objects used in javascript/vb "new ActiveXObject()"?

Tags: javascript, c++, vbscript, activex, atl

There are objects which you can create in Windows' javascript/vb shell like this:

```
x = new ActiveXObject("name");
x.aMethod();
```

What is the **technical name** for them (ATL? ActiveX? ActiveX control? Automation? or...?)

And how are they **different** from objects that can be used in IE this way:

```
<object id="aName" classid="CLSID:1234567-..." codebase="http://somewhere"></object>
```

Comment: They're not called ActiveX objects?

Comment: nop (base on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActiveX)

Comment: OK, well in practice I've only heard them called either "ActiveX objects" or "ActiveX controls". (Unless you want to go back ten years or so when we called them "COM objects" or "COM controls".)

Comment: yes, it seems the naming has never been exact and people refer to both of them as "ActiveX object/controls" but there must be a difference or an exact name (ActiveX Server Component or ATL COM Object for example?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the technical name for them (ATL? ActiveX? ActiveX control? Automation? or...?)

Internet Explorer refers to both as *ActiveX controls* (see the *Type* column in the image below)

[image]

- **ATL (Active Template Library)** refers to a library that simplifies the creation of COM objects, including ActiveX controls.
- **Automation** refers to the technology for inter-process communication on which ActiveX controls are built.  ActiveX controls may be referred to as *Automation objects*.

> And how are they different from objects that can be used in IE this way

ActiveX controls instantiated through JavaScript are referred to by **Programmatic Identifier (ProgID)** and have no user interface.  Controls placed in the document as `<object>` tags, commonly referred to as *user controls*, are specified by **Class Identifier (ClassID)** and *may have* a user interface.  `<object>` tags also inherit various traits of HTML elements.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation of ActiveXObject function in MSDN:

An object that provides an interface to an **Automation object**.

An automation object is a COM object whose class exposes IDispatch.

ActiveX control, strictly speaking, is designed for a container. The OLE interfaces like IOleObject and IOleControl define the contract between the control and its host. An ActiveX may or may not provide automation interface via IDispatch. If an ActiveX does provide automation interface, we call it a dual Interface ActiveX or scriptable ActiveX, which means the ActiveX can be used in late-binding languages like Jscript.

ATL is a class library in Visual C++. It is designed to writing ActiveX , yes, but it can also be used to write windows services and other libraries (e.g. MFC) and apps. Of course it is not necessary in writing ActiveX, there were many ActiveX controls written before it was invented.

There are many other components that are also associated with ActiveX. ActiveX documents (e.g. Adobe Reader, Microsoft Word) is a type of documents that can be hosted in ActiveX documents servers, such as an Internet Explorer frame. An ActiveX-enabled application (e.g. Microsoft Word, Windows Media Player) runs in its own process but can be automated via automation interface.

Answer (score 0):

This family of late-bound objects are most often referred to as COM (Common Object Model) Objects.  The loosely applied term "COM" typically encompasses any OLE, OLE Automation, ActiveX, COM+, or DCOM object.  Essentially, this is any object that provides a scriptable (IUnknown) interface through any number of technologies.